# Converting a Rowheader into Coulmn Using Pivot in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Id  Name_id Name
1   3500    aaa
```

I need output like this .Kindly help using pivot

```
    column_Name    Values
    Id             1   
    Name_id        3500
    Name           aaa
```

Comment: Output is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You could this using `UNION ALL`. You may want to add a `CONVERT` to prevent conversion error.

```
SELECT
    Column_Name = 'ID',
    [Values] = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ID)
FROM Your_Table
UNION ALL
SELECT
    Column_Name = 'Name_Id',
    [Values] = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Name_Id)
FROM Your_Table
UNION ALL
SELECT
    Column_Name = 'Name',
    [Values] = Name
FROM Your_Table
```

Answer (score 0):

I will do this using `Cross Apply` with `table valued constructor`

```
SELECT column_name,
       [values]
FROM   Yourtable
       CROSS apply (VALUES('Id',CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), Id)),
                          ('Name_id',CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), Name_id)),
                          ('name',name)) cs (column_name, [values])
```

Comment: thanks is there a way to do dynamically? using pivot?